# Macbook Pro 2019 16" can't provide 4K60Hz feed to external monitor vis usb-c to usb-c cable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt

So I have recently got a new 32" 4K monitor from Lenovo which supports input + power delivery through a provided USB-C cable. This cable works perfectly when connected to a MacBook Air with M1 chip and provides 4K at 144hz. However, when connected to my 2019 MacBook Pro through any of the four thunderbolt 3 ports it only shows options for the 4K native resolution at 30Hz max. Here is the stuff I have tried so far:

- MacOS display settings: clicking on "scaled option" with the option key pressed and selecting any of the "low resolution" options doesn't work either.
- resetting the NVRAM
- SwtichRes to create a resolution manually and switch to it => doesn't work
- BetterDisplay only shows 4K at 30Hz also
- Hdmi cable through usb-c adapter
- DP cable through usb c adapter

THe only thing I haven't tried yet is to buy a display port to usb c cable (without and adapter). I will do that if I get no answer here, but I first wanted to see if there was a way to avoid that. I also haven't tried setting the DP port of the TB3 ports on the MacBook Pro to another version as was suggested in some other posts, since I have only found ways to do that working with previous version of OSX.

Also, probably good to know is that I can set it to 2560x1440 resolution at 120Hz.
The monitor also works flawlessly with my Windows PC at 144hz in 4K.
The monitor in question is the Lenovo Legion Y32p-30.

tested with another 4k 60Hz monitor, the Dell Ultrasharp and it works well with a usb-c connection.
[image: my system if that helps]

Comment: Try getting a cable that supports DisplayPort 1.4 or later.  Buy from known brands like Belkin and Cables2Go.  Don't get the no-name stuff from Amazon/eBay

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Yeah I have bought I'll try that today. But isn't it weird that it worked perfectly with another monitor with the same cable?